# Error of 'Source (dirPath) and destination (iisApp) are not compatible for the given operation' when trying to deploy package

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm trying to deploy a package via the MSDeploy task from within MSBuild.

I have configured two Item Groups to represent my source and destination.

The source is a package I have created eg. Solution.zip
The destination is IIS 7 on a remote server.

The configuration looks like this :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DeploySource Include="package">
        <Path>$(PackagePath)</Path>
    </DeploySource>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <DeployDestination Include="iisApp">
        <ComputerName>https://myserver.com/msdeploy.axd</ComputerName>
        <UserName>XXXXXXXX</UserName>
        <Password>XXXXXXXX</Password>
        <AuthType>Basic</AuthType>
        <Path>Default Web Site/Umbraco.Web_deploy</Path>
    </DeployDestination>
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <ConfigFileName>Staging.config</ConfigFileName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I then call the MSDeploy task within MSBuild like this :

```
<Target Name="Deploy_v2">
    <!-- Using ContinueOnError due to a bug in MSDeploy task-->
    <MSDeploy
        ContinueOnError="true" 
        ToolPath="C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3"
        Verb="sync"
        Source="@(DeploySource)"
        Destination="@(DeployDestination)" 
        AllowUntrusted="true"
        Replace="objectName=filepath,match=Configs\$(ConfigFileName),replace=web.config"
    />
</Target>
```

This results in the following command line execution

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe -source:package='C:\CLIENTS\DAM\Components\Umbraco\SiteTemplate_v6_1_6\Output\Package\UmbracoTemplate_v6_1_6.zip' -dest:iisApp='Default WebSite/Umbraco.Web_deploy',ComputerName='https://myserver.com/msdeploy.axd',UserName='XXXXXXX',Password='XXXXXXXX',AuthType='Basic' -verb:sync -replace:objectName=filepath,match=Configs\Staging.config,replace=web.config -allowUntrusted
```

Which unfortunately results in the following error :

```
MSDEPLOY : Error: Source (dirPath) and destination (iisApp) are not compatible for the given operation.
```

It seems to me that MSDeploy is viewing my package as a dirPath. When I created the package it did use a dirPath as its source.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states `dirPath` and `iisApp` are not compatible providers, although `iisApp` does use `dirPath`. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569054%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

`iisApp` can take a directory as the source so try packaging the target directory via `iisApp` as follows:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:iisApp=c:\inetpub\wwwroot -dest:package=Package.zip
```

Btw if you are using Visual Studio you can generate an MSDeploy package using `MSBuild` with `/t:Publish`.